# compile DOM into angularjs in Rails ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, angularjs-directive

I tried to include angular.js into my current Rails app (3.2.12).

During render the flash page at users#index action, there is a ng-animate directive ( < disappear="fadeOutUp" > )  won't appear in ajax calls, but works on direct HTML calls.

I think the problem is angular needs to recompile the DOM. (on new DOM contents). But how can I access the $compile in javascript (index.js.erb)...??? or how do re-compile the angular element in javascript

edit:
I have managed to include the flash, but the ng-click is not responsive after the ajax call??

### users_controller.rb

```
def index
  @users = User.all.pagainate( page: params[:page] )
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { flash[:info] = "user#index HTML" }
    format.js { flash.now[:info]= "users#index ajax" }
  end 
end
```

### _flash.html.erb

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
<div class="alert-box" ng-if="flash.<%= key%>">
    <a class="close" ng-click="flash.<%= key%>=false">&times</a>

    <h5><%= key %></h5>
    <p><%= value.html_safe%></p>

</div>
<% end %>
```

### index.js.erb

```
alert("start");

htmlCode = "<%=escape_javascript( render(partial: 'layouts/flash', locals: {flash: flash}) )%>"
elem = angular.element("div#flash")
scope = elem.scope()
x = scope.tryUpdates(elem , htmlCode)
alert("end")
```

### script.js.coffee

```
app = angular.module("app", ["ngAnimate"] )
.....
controllers.contentCtrl = ( ["$scope", "Flash", "$compile", ($scope, Flash, $compile) ->
$scope.tryUpdates = (elem, content) ->
    console.log ( "tryUpdates( #" + elem.attr('id') + ", " + content + ")"  )
    angular.element(elem.attr('id') )
    $scope.$apply( angular.element('#flash').html( $compile(content) )($scope)   )

] )
```

Answer (score 3):

i finally found it.

by using **injector()** method and perform **scope.$digest()** at the of the call in the index.js.erb

so it would be

```
htmlCode = "<%=escape_javascript( render(partial: 'layouts/flash', locals: {flash: flash}) )%>"
elem = angular.element("div#flash")
$compile = elem.injector().get('$compile')
scope = elem.scope()
elem.html( $compile(flashCode)(scope) )
scope.$digest()
```

and it's done.

Comment: hey what is flashCode?

Comment: @davidesantangelo, flashcode = whatever you want in the flash message(html version). So generic error messages can be displayed, ie new user Form before it has been submitted ( new password match checking) or after it is been submitted (login failed errors)